# Apollo query has the wrong data from cache

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Apollo query has the wrong data from cache in my react app.

If I set query's fetchPolicy to 'network-only', everything work properly.

So I think it is a cache problem.

I have been working hard trying to solve the problem and see articles about apollo cache, but I still can't solve the problem.

Here are my results after querying:

parameter memberId is null (result is correct)

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "totalQuantity": 12,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "quantity": 11,
        "Member": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "quantity": 1,
        "Member": {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "B"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 88,
    "totalQuantity": 1,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "quantity": 1,
        "Member": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

parameter memberId is 9 (result is correct)

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "totalQuantity": 1,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 28,
        "quantity": 1,
        "Member": {
          "id": 9,
          "name": "B"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

parameter memberId is 1 (result is correct)

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "totalQuantity": 11,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "quantity": 11,
        "Member": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 88,
    "totalQuantity": 1,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "quantity": 1,
        "Member": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but when I back to parameter is null the result is wrong

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "totalQuantity": 11,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "quantity": 11,
        "Member": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 88,
    "totalQuantity": 1,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "quantity": 1,
        "Member": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Member B (id = 9) is disappear..

and I back to parameter is 9 (result is wrong)

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "totalQuantity": 11,
    "Orders": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "quantity": 11,
        "Member": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "A"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I get the Member A's data instead of Member B

Can someone help me? Thanks

---

My client configuration (cache is InMemoryCache)

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    httpLink,
  ]),
  cache,
  dataIdFromObject: o => ${o.id}${o.__typename},
});
```

I use queryHook to wrap my component

```
const queryHook = graphql(FETCH_ORDER_GROUP_SHIPMENT_LIST, {
  options: ownProps => ({
  variables: {
    memberId: ownProps.options.memberId || null,
  },
}),
  props: ({
    data: {
      orderGroupShipmentList,
    },
  }) => ({
    orderGroupShipmentList: orderGroupShipmentList || [],
  });
```

Also I use Query tag(other data) to wrap my content

and its parameter is memberId as well.

the structure like this

```
<Query
  variables={{ memberId: options.memberId || null }}
  query={FETCH_MEMBER_LIST_QUERY}>
  content that use orderGroupShipmentList and memberList
</Query>
```

I don't know if this is specific enough

Let me know if this is not specific enough

Thanks

---

2019-09-16

For those who facing the same problem:

https://kamranicus.com/posts/2018-03-06-graphql-apollo-object-caching

Comment: please share the code also

Comment: It would be beneficial to see your client configuration, as well as the code that actually uses your queries.

Comment: If these are the responses you're getting from the server, it looks like the `__typename` is missing, which suggests you've intentionally set `addTypename` to `false` in your client config. Is that the case?

Comment: @DhavalChheda updated thank you!

Comment: @DanielRearden updated thank you, and __typename is exist I just ignore that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have different ids for that type on the returned results for your query. For example, you have different results for id 87 based on memberId, so the cache will be overwritten by your second query and since apollo does not refetch queries already made by default it will continue to look at the overwritten result.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You are right! By the way, I found an article that explained about my question: https://kamranicus.com/posts/2018-03-06-graphql-apollo-object-caching

Comment: @Anymore: thank you for the link. I met this issue today and I finally know why

Comment: @HoangTrinh  I'm glad that I can help you

Answer (score 0):

@Anymore - can we see you FETCH_MEMBER_LIST_QUERY code? Are you fetching id's for all the data? Without the ids it won't be able to match relations.

Have you tried using Apollo Client DevTools - they will let you easily view the contents of the cache. It can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-devtools) and the Chrome Webstore [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm)

Using this you will be able to see if the item is being cached correctly.

Comment: I am sure that I fetch id's for all the data.

Comment: I used the Apollo Client DevTools found that when I change parameter memberId from 9 to 1 the cache data is right

Comment: but when I change parameter back to 9 the cache didn't cache the right data (cache data remain same)

Comment: I will update my question later for specific explanation